# A partial outer product

Tags: programming, functional-style

Here is an example of what I want to do:

Suppose I have a collection of samples `S = {s1, s2, s3, ...}`. I want to construct the correlation matrix (and yes, this might already be built in, but this is just an example). The obvious way of doing this is by doing `Outer[Correlation, S, S]`, but obviously this does (slightly more than) twice the amount of work necessary. There are ugly ways to fix this, for example, defining a function

```
 corr[i_, j_]:= If[i>j, Correlation[S[[i]], S[[j]]], 0]
```

but this does not appeal (and it is also space-wasteful). Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: In other words, are you trying to more efficiently implement `Outer[ #1, #2, #2]&`?  Or is your question more specific?

Comment: @jjc385 I am trying to do things more efficiently when the function is symmetric in the arguments, so one does not do the computation twice over.

Comment: @IgorRivin does my answer work. If not let me know so that i can delete it !

Comment: @Igor Ah, yes, of course the function needs to be symmetric in the arguments.  Is it possible `Outer` does this automatically when its first argument is `Orderless`?

Comment: @Igor Apparently `Outer` is not so smart.  `With[{S = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]},
 Reap[ Outer[Function[, Sow@ff@##, Orderless], S, S] ] // 
  Last /* Flatten /* Length
 ]` returns 100.

Comment: @AliHashmi Yes, that does work, but it is not so different from what I suggest Maybe there is only one real way to do this....

Comment: @Igor, should the desired output be a triangle or a square matrix filled with the copied but unevaluated symmetric complement?

Answer (score 4):

```
S = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
ls = SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> Correlation[S[[i]], S[[j]]] /; i > j,
ConstantArray[Length@S,2]] // Quiet;

ls//Normal

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {Correlation[s2, s1], 0, 0, 0}, {Correlation[s3, s1], 
Correlation[s3, s2], 0, 0}, {Correlation[s4, s1], 
Correlation[s4, s2], Correlation[s4, s3], 0}} *)
```

this is same as:

```
ls = Outer[Correlation, S, S] // Quiet;
Do[If[i <= j, ls[[i, j]] = 0], {i, 4}, {j, 4}];
ls
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {Correlation[s2, s1], 0, 0, 0}, {Correlation[s3, s1], 
Correlation[s3, s2], 0, 0}, {Correlation[s4, s1], 
Correlation[s4, s2], Correlation[s4, s3], 0}} *)
```